# Is there a chess AI that can force checkmate on a specified square?

Tags: engines, problems

I'm looking for a program that can force a lone king into checkmate on a specific square. Are there any programs out there that can do this?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the great question ChessNoob3000, and welcome to chess.stackexchange.com

I don't know of any chess program right now ("AI" or otherwise) which can force checkmate on a particular square. The idea of "conditional problems", e.g. white must mate with a certain piece, was popular in the 19th century, before the arrival of software which can solve much more complex problems, but they are now a bit of a backwater. If you wrote a program specializing in conditional problems, you could be able to apply it to [hundreds of unproven problems](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/search.jsp?expression=k%3D%27Constrained+problem%27)!

Related work is in Francois' Labelle's ["Jacobi" program](https://wismuth.com/jacobi/). This does allow for conditions, but is strictly applicable to help problems and proof games. It would not apply to adversarial stipulations e.g. "mate in 2" or "self-mate in 2".

You might post a feature request for [Popeye in github](https://github.com/thomas-maeder/popeye) , or if you are a programmer you might want to contribute to the Popeye open source yourself. Chat with Thomas Maeder about this: conditional problems for non-help stipulations is definitely a hole currently.